# why does my program jump out of loop after packaging with maven?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, tcp, package

I have written a program to send current IP between my servers using TCP/IP. when I run the program in IDE everything works fine and I get the expected result but when I package it using Maven, the program runs only once and immediately jumps out of the loop. can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

```
public String getIP () throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress myIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    //System.out.println("My IP Address is:");
    //System.out.println(myIP.getHostAddress());
    String IP = myIP.getHostAddress();

    return IP;
}

public String getID(){

    JFrame f;

    f=new JFrame();
    String ID=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(f,"Enter GSID");

    return ID;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Socket s1 = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedReader is = null;
    PrintWriter pwr = null;

    client obj = new client();
    String CID = obj.getID();
    String response = null;

    while(true) {

        String ServerIP = "173.16.1.5";
            s1 = new Socket(ServerIP, 4445);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream()));
            pwr = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());

            // send ID to Server
            pwr.println(CID);
            pwr.flush();
            response = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server Response : " + response);

            // get IP and send to Server
            client IP = new client();
            String CIP = IP.getIP();

            pwr.println(CIP);
            pwr.flush();
            response = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server Response : " + response);

            // send time
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            pwr.println(dtf.format(now));
            pwr.flush();
            response = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server Response : " + response);

            is.close();
            pwr.close();
            br.close();
            s1.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed");

            JFrame f;

            f=new JFrame();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So just to confirm -- Do you see the output once only, and then the program stops ?
Are you sure there are no exceptions ?

Comment: True, I see the output only once and not a second time, there shouldn't be any exceptions because there are none in ide. but if there are, how can I see the exceptions in a console out of ide? (I tried cmd but didn't work)